# How to find css file of scss file in angular project

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have created the angular project in VS Code using the following command.

```
ng new my-app --style=scss
```

by following this [github link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap)

Now every style sheet that is being created using angular-cli is with extension of .scss instead of .css

Now there is a requirement to check that how Sass is being converted to css because I am new to Sass. I am facing some issues in designing thus it would be nice for me to look at css file.

I have searched in those folder where scss file exists but there I couldn't find css file. Please help

**Update**

[image]

Look at this picture, when I created the component using cli, it created .scss instead of css so I need to look for css file.

Comment: css will be compiled on build

Comment: ok building my project using this command ng build –prod –aot

Comment: still no where I could find css file result of scss.

Comment: you can specify the output folder for compiled code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838480/how-to-compile-typescript-files-in-a-specific-folder-with-angular-quickstart

Comment: you may find your css inlined in script tags at the end of head  https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to find a way to view my compiled `.scss` files as a `.css` file.
Before I only saw the raw `.scss` files when inspecting from Chrome.

The trick was setting some flags in the `angular.json` file so it will tell `webpack` (what angular-cli uses to build the app) that I want the `.scss` files served as `.css` along with a sourcemap of the file:

```json
./angular.json

{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "my-prject": { <-- or whatever your project is named
      "architect": {
        "configurations": {
          "production": { // <-- production is default, you might be working w/ custom configurations [development, test, w/e]
            ...
            "sourceMap": true, <-- will serve source maps w/ the file so you can view it in the browser easily
            "extractCss": true, <-- actually serve the .css files and not the .scss files
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once that is updated, restart the dev server or rebuild your application
then you can go into chrome dev tools and look at find the `styles.css` file (or whatever you have the file name set to) and view it:
[image: Screenshot of Chrome Source with compiled .css file]

If you are working on local then:

```json
local {
 "sourceMap": true,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sass in Angular 2 are always converted into Css in run time when you compile and build the project. However if you are using any other environment like Gulp tasks and watches, you can run 'sass --watch input.scss output.css'

Comment: I have build the project but could not find in component folder or in dist folder. searched in windows explorer with 'css', but could not find a single file with .css extension.

Comment: I have noted "I am facing some issues in designing thus it would be nice for me to look at css file". so, if you have some design issue, we can always inspect an element as you might know or other people already mentioned. all you need to do is find which part of sass rendered that designed issue css in element inspect of chrome etc., once you find css selector, just overwrite that selector in sass itself. Another solution may be just create css file for that specific area and import in SASS like this. `@import '/public/css/bootstrap.css';`

Answer (score 1):

As folks have already mentioned, the css is built at runtime.  You can still set the result using inspect in chrome or firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a requirement to check the generated CSS when you find something wrong and Chrome Inspector can't help! So this is definitely a good question, which is why I'm here.

To summarize, @y_vyshnevska is right that "you may find your css inlined in script tags at the end of head", and he also gave an in-depth link: https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975 on the topic. I put it here in case you neglect it.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks not possible to view compiled css files at a runtime.

However, you can do the following trick: angular applies components' styles using `<style>` attribute. Find the one you need in elements inspector (you can search there using `ctrl (or cmd) + f`.

After you've found the stylesheet you need, you'll see it's truncated. To see the entire content, click on the style element and select "Store as global variable". After that in console run

```
copy(Object.values(temp1.sheet.cssRules).map(r => r.cssText).join('\n'))
```

This will copy all css to your buffer
[image]
[image]

Comment: Getting an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cssRules') at <anonymous>

Comment: @VarunSharma are you sure you're selecting the <style> element?

Comment: ok thanks it works now. But, I got another error because copy function was not working in Chrome Dev Tools so had to run "document.querySelector('#copy').remove();
" and then re-ran the command and the styles were copied to the clipboard.